# Организация доступа к почтовому ящику Outlook, используя REST API и OAuth2

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, azure

Вводные данные:

1. Есть email, на который приходят всякие письма, которые нужно автоматически обрабатывать. Email зарегистрирован на учетную запись предприятия.
2. Согласно [инструкции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) было зарегистрировано и настроено приложение
3. Для авторизации и аутентификации установлен модуль [msal](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#confidentialclientapplication) для python, который поставляется Microsoft

С пониманием протоколов и что такое `JWT` проблем нет. И я даже получаю token доступа

```py
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
from msal.authority import Authority

password = "**********"
auth = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}"
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, client_credential=password, authority=auth)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",])
token = result['access_token']

print(token)

#OUT
# eyJ0eX.................
```

Возникают вопросы каким образом подключиться к *конкретному* почтовому ящику и им управлять?

**UPD**
Разобрался в том, что есть различные потоки авторизации и каждый токен имеет собственные разрешения (добавил разрешения для чтения почты), но так и не могу выбрать необходимый и получить приемлемый результат для работы с почтой.

Comment: Не понятно, на каком этапе зависли. Токен есть? ОК, смотрите скоупы. Должны быть `Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite` [согласно этому](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Дальше отправляете запрос `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages` - также согласно спеке. В запросе указываете заголовок с токеном. Получаете от этого REST-сервера ответ, его обрабатываете. Как я понял, `id|userPrincipalName` - это id ящика, или [логин](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-userprincipalname)

Comment: @TotalPusher Да, пробираюсь чуть дальше и дальше. Если б я знал, что microsoft это такое болото, не взялся бы... Тут чтобы в документации разобраться, курить и курить.... `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages` корректно не отрабатывает -> получаю `Resource '<name>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present`. Каждый шаг - это ошибка, каждый шаг - это кривая документация, матерюсь...

Comment: Как я понял, проблема в `{id | userPrincipalName}`. Также в спеке, в разделе Users есть пример. `/users('$AdeleVance@contoso.com')`. Попробуйте такую нотацию как [вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

Comment: PS. Есть еще [такая штука](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Comment: @TotalPusher как я могу вас отблагодарить? =) Доки, там где про знак доллара, есть второй пункт, который гласит `заменить все знаки решеток на %23`. Поскольку это все цепляется автоматом, я даже внимания туда не обращал. Матерюсь....=) Как я должен находить такую информацию....?, вообще не дружелюбный енвиромент

Comment: Напишите ответ на свой вопрос для будущих поколений :) `Как я должен находить такую информацию` - чтением доки, а также сорцов пакетов, которые это используют. И тестов. Я в питоне не силен. Но для PHP нашел пакет для работы с Графом. [В нем](https://github.com/wapacro/laravel-msgraph-mail/blob/master/src/MsGraphMailTransport.php#L64), адрес подставляется так: `$url = str_replace('{from}', urlencode($payload['from']['emailAddress']['address']), $this->apiEndpoint);`. Это как раз замена `на %23`. Я не стал писать это выше, чтобы не запутывать. Ну и думал, что вы в курсе про urlencode.

Comment: @TotalPusher обязательно напишу ответ, в этом смысле я дисциплинирован. А остальное - это возмущение в воздух (документация разбросана и не приветлива), поскольку я использую `msal` я даже не заглядывал в URL, я просто брал `userPrincipalName` из ответа и не видел, что он содержит. Я точно в курсе про urlencode

Comment: Это экосистема мелкомягких. Прячем код, поставляем бинарники. Нанимаем индусов. Embrace, extend and extinguish. [MS Loves Linux](http://techrights.org/2019/09/09/control-of-media/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Решение найдено**. Здесь опишу весь порядок действий, как используя библиотеку `msal` добиться доступа к почте Outlook через приложение созданного в `azure`. Порядок действий - тестовый, шаг за шагом

**Причина использования**: `microsoft` вводит более строгие правила доступа к своим ресурсам и мы были уведомлены, что доступ по протоколу `smtp` будет невозможен для наших решений. Следовательно, необходимо было разработать систему доступа через `oAuth2`, как того рекомендует `microsoft`.

Итак по порядку

1. Для начала необходимо было выбрать один из потоков авторизации [из предлагаемых](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows). Мною был выбран `on behalf flow`
2. Затем создается приложение в `azure active directory` -> `App registrations`
3. При регистрации указал название, `single tenant` только для доступа из организации и `Redirect URL` = http://localhost:7999/
4. Далее в приложении в пункте `Certificates & secrets` добавил одну сущность (обязательно скопировать и сохранить, иначе потом будет не доступно, но можно будет создать новый секрет)
5. В пункте `API permissions` добавил разрешения (Add a permission -> Graph -> delegated -> в этом списке выбирать): `User.Read`, `Mail.ReadWrite`
6. После того как нужные разрешения выбраны нажать `Grant admin consent for ...`
7. Далее переходим к python и msal. Устанавливаем

```
pip install msal
```

8. Создаем конфиг

```py
config = {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}",
    "client_id": "client-id",
    "scope": ["User.Read", "Mail.ReadWrite"],
    "secret":"secret",
}
```

"authority" -> вместо `tenant` вставить значение, которое находится `azure active directory` -> `App registrations` -> выбрать само приложение -> значение для `Directory (tenant) ID`
"client_id" -> здесь же, но значение `Application (client) ID`
"secret" -> созданный в пункте 4 секрет

9. Импортируем библиотеки и создаем объект для приложения

```py
import json
import requests
import msal

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    client_credential=config["secret"],)
```

10. На данном этапе я воспользовался простым `http server` от python и в стороннем окне `CMD` запустил сервер

```py
py -m http.server 7999
```

11. В python где объявлял объект класса `msal` вводим команду

```py
url = app.get_authorization_request_url(scopes=config["scope"], response_type='code')
print(url)

# https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=client-id&response_type=code&scope=Mail.ReadWrite+User.Read+offline_access+openid+profile
```

12. Скопировал ссылку в браузер и авторизовался под той почтой откуда буду читать письма и дал разрешения.
13. В браузере появится ссылка, которая будет содержать некий `code`. Вот он нам и нужен

```
code = "dsf870f4Kmkasidd......"
```

14. И следующей командой получаем токены доступа

```py
res = app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code=code, scopes=config["scope"])
```

15. И читаем почту

```py
data = requests.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages",headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res['access_token']},).json()
```

Все заработало. Следующее отсается только настроить сохранение токенов в cache (msal имеет для этого интерфейс), автоматизировать и использовать.

Устал я от `microsoft`, честно

Comment: `Скопировал ссылку в браузер и авторизовался` - можно сделать лучше. В OAuth2 можно авторизовываться [разными способами](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/). Вы выбрали способ по коду, и поэтому пришлось заходить через браузер. Для машин лучше использовать Client Credentials Grant (Client credentials в MSAL). Тогда захода в браузер не потребуется, все будет автоматически. Вот тут [подробнее](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows)

Comment: Да, улучшить можно. Я указал, что вариант тестовый и изменения могут и должны вноситься. Я для тех кто будет копать как и я, снизить время проведенное в чтеии доков